# What is the correct CSS nesting sequence to target the item I need to target

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply some styling to a sub menu item that I have designated with the class 'menu-mine', but I am unsure of the correct nesting sequence to use.

I am trying to transform part of my menu by changing the font size and ensuring it is uppercase, but am having trouble getting the nested selectors correct.

I want to apply it only to the menu heading with the class 'menu-mine' in the link. I am unable to apply the css class to any other selector as I am working with joomla. This is the (edited) version of the menu, and the CSS selector in question is in the 'OPAL' section.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-mainmenu visible-md-block visible-lg-block vpf-mainmenu affix-on-scroll" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse vpf-mega-menu-container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav vpf-menu" data-animate="slide" data-easing-open="linear" data-easing-close="linear" data-easing-time="100">
// other code

<li class="menuitem item-464 level-2 submenu col-xs-4"><a class="menu-mine" href="/index.php/en/by-stone/opal" ><span class="menu-group"><span class="menu-title">OPAL</span></span></a></li>
<li class="menuitem item-465 level-2 submenu col-xs-4"><a href="/index.php/en/by-stone/citrine-by-stone" ><span class="menu-group"><span class="menu-title">CITRINE</span></span></a></li>
</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This didn't work.

```
.navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2 > a.menu-mine, .navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2 a.menu-mine span.menu-group > span {
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The expected outcome is that the menu header 'Opal' will be in uppercase and the specified font size.

Comment: `nav > div > div > div > ul > li:first-of-type > a > span > span` Probably don't need the child combinators: `>` but HTML can get messy with CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to include `first-of-type`.  I've added it to your declarations without suggesting any other modifications.  I've added `color: red` to make the output clearer to researchers.

```css
.navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2:first-of-type a.menu-mine,
.navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2:first-of-type a.menu-mine span.menu-group > span
{
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-mainmenu visible-md-block visible-lg-block vpf-mainmenu affix-on-scroll" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse vpf-mega-menu-container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav vpf-menu" data-animate="slide" data-easing-open="linear" data-easing-close="linear" data-easing-time="100">
                  <li class="menuitem item-464 level-2 submenu col-xs-4"><a class="menu-mine" href="/index.php/en/by-stone/opal" ><span class="menu-group"><span class="menu-title">OPAL</span></span></a></li>
                  <li class="menuitem item-465 level-2 submenu col-xs-4"><a href="/index.php/en/by-stone/citrine-by-stone" ><span class="menu-group"><span class="menu-title">CITRINE</span></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Actually, I just checked in Edge, and it doesn't seem to look the same, yet it works perfectly in chrome. Is there a fix for edge?

Comment: I am not at my computer, maybe `nth-child(1)`?  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work - am I using it correctly?  .navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2:nth-child(1) a.menu-mine,
.navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2 a.menu-mine span.menu-group span.menu-title:nth-child(1)
{
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: How about first-child? `.navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2:first-child a.menu-mine,
.navbar-mainmenu .navbar-nav li.level-2:first-child a.menu-mine span.menu-group > span
`?